# Strange crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) scrolling UITableView reentering app after background

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, scroll

I'm using an UITableView with standard cell with subtitle and UIImageView. The scrolling is ok till I exit from the app. Then it goes background (I make nothing on delegate backgroun methods) and when I rerun the app, on the same view with the uitable, the scroll it's ok for some rows then the app crash in the method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

the code of the method is:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

  ALog(@"TRACE");

    }

  // Configure the cell...

 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

 NSDictionary *cellContent = (NSDictionary *)[self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 Restaurant * r = (Restaurant *)[cellContent valueForKey:@"ristorante"];

 cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0 green:245.0 blue:245.0 alpha:0.8];

 cell.textLabel.text = r.nome;

 cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];

 cell.detailTextLabel.text = [r.indirizzo convertToString];

 UIImage *img = r.tipo.image; //[UIImage imageNamed:@"loghetto_pne.png"];

 cell.imageView.image = img; 

  //cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

  //cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

 float sw= 48/img.size.width;

 float sh= 48/img.size.height;

 cell.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sw,sh);

  //[img release];



    return cell;
```

The crash is in the line:

```
cell.imageView.image = img;
```

From the stack trace I see that the execution goes on some internal framework code and then crash. The exception is not always the same (often is CATransaction count --> object di not respond to selector etc)

The code for Restaurant and Tipologia:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class Zona;
@class Indirizzo;
@class Tipologia;

@interface Restaurant : NSObject {

@private
    NSUInteger idx;
    NSString *nome;
    NSString *telefono;
    Indirizzo *indirizzo;
    Zona *zona;
    Tipologia *tipo;

}

-(id)initWithIdx:(NSUInteger)index name:(NSString *)ristoName tel:(NSString *)ristoTel address:(Indirizzo *)ristoAdd zone:(Zona *)ristoZone;

@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger idx;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *nome;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *telefono;
@property (nonatomic,retain) Indirizzo *indirizzo;
@property (nonatomic,retain) Zona *zona;
@property (nonatomic,retain) Tipologia *tipo;


@end
```

Restaurant implementation:

```
#import "Restaurant.h"
#import "Zona.h"
#import "Indirizzo.h"
#import "Macro.h"


@implementation Restaurant

@synthesize idx, nome, indirizzo, telefono, zona, tipo;

-(id)initWithIdx:(NSUInteger)index name:(NSString *)ristoName tel:(NSString *)ristoTel address:(Indirizzo *)ristoAdd zone:(Zona *)ristoZone {
    [self init];
    bool error = NO;
    if (self) {
        idx = index;
        nome = [ristoName retain];
        telefono = [ristoTel retain];
        indirizzo = [ristoAdd retain];
        zona = [ristoZone retain];
    }

    return (error) ? nil : self;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        idx = 0;
        nome = @"";
        telefono = @"";
        indirizzo = nil;
        zona = nil;
        tipo = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [nome release];
    [indirizzo release];
    [telefono release];
    [zona release];
    ALog(@"TRACE");
    [tipo release];
    ALog(@"TRACE");
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Tipologia interface and implementation:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum {
    kTipoRestUnknown = 0,
    kTipoRestRestaurant,
    kTipoRestBrunch,
    kTipoRestPizza,
    kTipoRestRegional,
    kTipoRestEthnic
} TipoRest;

@class ImageTest;

@interface Tipologia : NSObject {

@private    
    NSInteger idx;
    NSString *desc;
    UIImage *image;
    TipoRest type;
}

-(id)initWithIndex:(NSInteger) index description:(NSString *)descr ofType:(TipoRest) type;

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger idx;
@property (nonatomic) TipoRest type;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *desc;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *image;


@end

#import "Tipologia.h"
#import "Macro.h"

@implementation Tipologia

@synthesize desc, idx, image, type;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory Management

-(id)initWithIndex:(NSInteger) index description:(NSString *)descr ofType:(TipoRest) type {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.idx = index;
        self.desc = descr;
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"immagineNA.png"];;
        self.type = type;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [desc release];
    desc = nil;
    ALog(@"TRACE");
    [image release];
    image = nil;
    ALog(@"TRACE");
    [super dealloc];    
}

-(void)release {
    ALog(@"tipo.idx: %i, tipo.count: %i, tipo.imag: %@, tipo.img.count: %i", idx, [self retainCount], image, [image retainCount]);
    [super release];
}
```

**EDIT 2** Some other code. The snippet where I initialize the images based on the type

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryStrTipo, -1, &query, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        restImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rest.png"];
        pizzaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pizza.png"];
        etnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"etnico.png"];
        brunchImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wineglass-blue.png"];

        while(sqlite3_step(query) == SQLITE_ROW) { 
            NSString *desc = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(query, 1)];
            tipo = [[Tipologia alloc] initWithIndex:sqlite3_column_int(query, 0)
                                                description:desc ofType:kTipoRestUnknown];
            ALog(@"tipo.idx: %i, retain count: %i",tipo.idx, [tipo retainCount]);
            if ([desc compare:kTipoDescRestaurant options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
                tipo.type = kTipoRestRestaurant;
                tipo.image = restImage;
            } else 
            if ([desc compare:kTipoDescPizza options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
                tipo.type = kTipoRestPizza;
                tipo.image = pizzaImage;
            } else
            if ([desc compare:kTipoDescEtnico options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
                tipo.type = kTipoRestEthnic;
                tipo.image = etnImage;
            } else
            if ([desc compare:kTipoDescBrunch options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
                tipo.type = kTipoRestBrunch;
                tipo.image = brunchImage;
            } else
            if ([desc compare:kTipoDescRegionale options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
                tipo.type = kTipoRestRegional;
            }


            dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tipo.idx], @"index", tipo.desc, @"desc", nil];
            [listaTipologie addObject:tipo];
            [listaTemp addObject:dictionary];
            ALog(@"tipo.idx: %i, retain count: %i",tipo.idx, [tipo retainCount]);
            [tipo release];
            [dictionary release];
        }
        [restImage release];
        [pizzaImage release];
        [etnImage release];
        [brunchImage release];
    }
```

Comment: Following some tips on the net about NSZombieEnabled, the console output now (on the same crash) write: 2010-12-16 23:07:11.891 romanelpiatto[1933:207] *** -[UIImage retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa141aa0 Now in that line I'm assigning an image to another... so how can I know what image was deallocated??

Comment: You obtain the image from `r.tipo.image` ... what is `tipo` and does it retain the image as well?

Comment: seems like r.tipo.image is already deallocated, check how you're setting its value and make sure you're retaining it.

Comment: I play aroud with some NSlog sentences full of retainCount. R is a class with a porperty (retain) Tipo with a property (retain) image (UIImage). Some scrolling before crash retainCount of image is 2 and after crash... I logged all dealloc method in all my code... so I cannot understand! The problem is only when quit app and reenter app...

Comment: Perhaps you should post the code for Restaurant and whatever type `tipo` is.

Comment: I added code on main queston... Tnx

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you posted. I assume the `image` property of the `Tipologia` objects get set somewhere to something other than the `immagineNA.png` at some point. Is there something else that releases those images one too many times?

Comment: Where are you setting the value of `tipo` in `Restaurant ` class? It's only set to `nil` in `init`

Comment: I just added the code used to initialize the images. After that code I set tipo in Restaurant: if (aux != NSNotFound) {
  rest.tipo = [listaTipologie objectAtIndex:aux];
  ALog(@"tipo.idx: %i, retain count: %i",rest.tipo.idx, [rest.tipo retainCount]);
  } Moreover I put some log (retain count of all restaurant.tipo.image) on applicationDidBecomeActive (after background) and crash on the call to retainCount. So it's not depending on the scrolling... somewhere between going background and returning active someone dealloc some of my images (1 on 4 image is deallocated). But I cannot figure it out

Comment: Did you make sure that `rest.tipo` isn't `nil`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure... I can see it in the debugger... With NsZombieEnabled I can see that the image which is deallocated is the instance inside tipo. And the problem is that that image is not nil, so I cannot write some check on nil value and realloc it...

Comment: Given that this only happens after waking up from the background, You might want to set some breakpoints in the methods that get called when that happens.  (applicationDidBecomeActive in your AppDelegate, viewWill/Did Appear in your View controllers, and any others that I can't think of right now.)  If you step through those code paths you might find something.  I'd keep an eye out for something that might be directly accessing one of the variables that are giving yo trouble instead of going through a setter or getter (i.e.  image = somthing instead of self.image=something)

Comment: Also feel free to post more of your code, andmyself and others can take a closer look.  I'd focus on the lifecylce callbacks in the AppDelegate, the relevant TableViewController and the model objects (Restraunt, etc)

Comment: Sorry, I had missed your edits where you did add more code. I spotted your problem and updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a retain on either r.tipo, or r.tipo.image.

if they are both synthesized properties, check that the property declaration contains a retain.

If you implemented you own getters and/or setters, check that you are retaining and releasing everything properly.

Edit:

I just saw the new code you posted.  Your problem is you are releasing UIImages that your code does not own.  Excluding all the conditional logic you basically do this:

```
//Incorrect
UIImage *myImagename = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]
yourclass.image = restImage;
[myImagename release];
```

This is incorrect because you never called alloc, copy or  retain on the myImage object. [UIImage imageMamed]  returns an autoreleased instance of a UIImage.  It is the same as doing this (also incorrect):

```
//Incorrect
UIImage *myImagename = [[UIImage alloc] initWithImage:@"foo.png"] autorelease];
yourclass.image = restImage;
[myImagename release];
```

You have two options. Either manage the release yourself:

```
UIImage *myImagename = [UIImage alloc] initWithImage:@"foo.png"];
yourclass.image = restImage;
[myImagename release];
```

Or let the autoreleased object do its thing:

```
UIImage *myImagename = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]
yourclass.image = restImage;
//Note: no release needed on yourClass.
```

In your specific code, you can take the second approach and it will look like this:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryStrTipo, -1, &query, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        restImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rest.png"];
        pizzaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pizza.png"];
        etnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"etnico.png"];
        brunchImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wineglass-blue.png"];

        while(sqlite3_step(query) == SQLITE_ROW) { 
            NSString *desc = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(query, 1)];
            tipo = [[Tipologia alloc] initWithIndex:sqlite3_column_int(query, 0)
                                                description:desc ofType:kTipoRestUnknown];
            ALog(@"tipo.idx: %i, retain count: %i",tipo.idx, [tipo retainCount]);
            if ([desc compare:kTipoDescRestaurant options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
                tipo.type = kTipoRestRestaurant;
                tipo.image = restImage;
            } else 
            if ([desc compare:kTipoDescPizza options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
                tipo.type = kTipoRestPizza;
                tipo.image = pizzaImage;
            } else
            if ([desc compare:kTipoDescEtnico options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
                tipo.type = kTipoRestEthnic;
                tipo.image = etnImage;
            } else
            if ([desc compare:kTipoDescBrunch options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
                tipo.type = kTipoRestBrunch;
                tipo.image = brunchImage;
            } else
            if ([desc compare:kTipoDescRegionale options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
                tipo.type = kTipoRestRegional;
            }


            dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tipo.idx], @"index", tipo.desc, @"desc", nil];
            [listaTipologie addObject:tipo];
            [listaTemp addObject:dictionary];
            ALog(@"tipo.idx: %i, retain count: %i",tipo.idx, [tipo retainCount]);
            [tipo release];
            [dictionary release];
        }
    }
```

Remember, the golden rule of iOS memory management:

If you use any method with the word copy, alloc, or new, you need to have a corresponding release.

And, of course, [Apple's Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.pdf) is the definitive resourse

Comment: see my last comment on previous post... Tnx

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue.

UIImage imageNamed return an autorelease object (I didn't know about it) and I use it to alloc the 4 image variables that then will be assigned to the property (via . sintax) and I release them after assigning.

Build & Analyze told me that the release statement could be wrong cause I didn't own the object anymore. Commented it out and the crash goes out...

The fault lines was the last in "EDIT 2" snippet of my question.

Thanks to all.